# Iteratively training an algorithm in scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which when given to an algorithm of `RandomForestClassifier` in `scikit-learn` causes the algorithm tu run out of memory. I'm using the `pandas` dataframes for loading the data. Is there a way so that I can iteratively train the algorithm i.e. I will slice the data into ten parts and train the algorithm over all parts to complete training over the dataset. Is this possible?

**EDIT COMPLETE TRACEBACK**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\major\solution-1.py", line 234, in <module>
    prep_data()
  File "F:\major\solution-1.py", line 160, in prep_data
    selector.fit(data[predictors], data['ED2'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1963, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2008, in _getitem_array
    return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1368, in take
    self._consolidate_inplace()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2411, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._protect_consolidate(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2402, in _protect_consolidate
    result = f()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2410, in f
    self._data = self._data.consolidate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3194, in consolidate
    bm._consolidate_inplace()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3199, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4189, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4212, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = new_values[argsort]
MemoryError
```

Comment: What is the size of your data ?

Comment: 200,000 rows and 337 columns...

Comment: Have you tried to apply the RandomForestClassifier to a really small subset of your data ? You didn't print the actual error. If the data fits in your RAM it should work if you're not using a big numbers of tree.

Comment: Yes I have, it does work with the subset of data. Edited the question to include the whole traceback.

Comment: What are the parameters of your RandomForestClassifier ?

Comment: I'm using the following parameters: `random_state=1,
  n_estimators = 20,    min_samples_split = 8,
  min_samples_leaf = 3
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your data in a csv file to know how big it is. We'll say that this quantity is **D**.
And **N** will be the number of trees you've used to create your RandomForestClassifier.
The RandomForest create N bootstrap of your data, so it creates new data that is DxN.
 If **DxN** is **bigger** than your **RAM**, yes you have a problem because you're using sklearn.

You probably want to use a **single model** before going to *ensemble models*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can iteratively train the data, use cross validation for slicing the data,code for it is provided in the link wriiten by emanuele.
https://github.com/emanuele/kaggle_pbr/blob/master/blend.py

For furter reference on ensembling check this link.
http://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/

I don't know much about memory error but I can say that data doesn't fit in your ram. First try subset of data and then full.